# Cocoapods ld: library not found for -lPods-Projectname

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I've installed cocoa pods library and some frameworks through it. Now when I compile project the build fails.

Error:
ld: library not found for -lPods-Project
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here part of text:

```
Ld /Users/polzovatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-bybevfqrgvqqldbzsgewqafpmylj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project app/Project normal i386
    cd /Users/polzovatel/Projects/iOS-master/Project_iPhone
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

What I need to do to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you run `pod install` and opened the `xyz.xcworkspace` instead of `xyz.xcproject`?

Comment: I know how to work with cocoa pods. I used this pods in a few projects, but this problem I see at first time. This project I downloaded from my clients. I already tried to delete xcworkspace and run pod install. Also I tried to delete Pods folder.

Comment: Opening the xyz.xcworkspace file worked for me. Somehow the Pod projects were not appearing in the IDE and I realized that the xcproject file was opened instead of the updated workspace.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Fixed it by deleting the `-lPods-Projectname.a` in **Link Binary** (for newer versions, delete the `-lPods-Projectname.a` under the **Frameworks** group).

Comment: You just saved me from a lot of embarrassment

Comment: where do i find this? :/

Comment: Thanks. Does anyone know why this solution actually worked?

Comment: After much perusing of various comments and solutions, this was the only one that worked for me! Thank you.

Comment: Why does this keep appearing and how do i possible automate this to delete prebuild?

Answer (score 47):

Whenever I execute "pod install" it leads me to spend several hours fixing build errors. So, I deleted CocoaPods stuff and do not have problems any more! Now I am lucky and happy man.

Start using Swift Package Manager (SPM). If your 3rd party lib still do not support SPM I encourage you to take action on adding SPM support on your own. Here is [instructions](https://getstream.io/blog/migrate-cocoapods-to-spm/).

Or create an issue for the 3rd party lib about adding support for SPM.

Comment: I experience a similar wish every few months, I have to admit.

Comment: Yes me too. But... if we can't who can ;)

Comment: A mere 6 weeks later and I'm back here looking again for why one target inexplicably fails with "ld: library not found for -lPods-AFNetworking", when the other essentially-identical target succeeds fine.

Comment: I agree with you... there are too many moving parts in CocoaPods. The cost / benefits ratio is pretty bad. Most of the time we spend more time fixing up CocoaPods problems than we would simply copy/pasting source files into our project. CocoaPods is somehow considered "state of the art" so it's hard to avoid but for private projects I might just skip it. So you have to manually update the source every now and then, but so what? On the other hand, code doesn't randomly break all the time.

Answer (score 24):

The exact location that you should remove your libs is at:

- Remove -lyourlibname.a in "Link Binary With Libraries" on "Build Phases" of your target.

Comment: This makes no sense to me, BUT IT WORKS!  I guess we don't need to link the pod library in child projects because we'll also link it in the parent project as well.

Answer (score 23):

You can try "Build Active Architecture Only" = YES . it may be solving problem.

Comment: The vital point is that the Build Active Architecture Only settings are the same for Pod and Project targets. Usually Yes for debug and No for release

Answer (score 20):

Ensure that `Build Active Architectures Only` settings for both of your project and the `Pods` project were equal for debug and release configuration! That's was a problem in my case.

Comment: You are a deity sir.

Comment: This was my problem as well. Once I set my project to match the Pods project settings for `Build Active Architectures Only` it worked.

Answer (score 14):

Make sure `Build Active Architectures Only` in your Project/Target and in your Pod/Target and Pod are the same.
**We often set the debug yes and set the release no.**

Comment: This was the problem for me. The Pods Project had "Build Active Architecture Only" = YES on Debug mode.

Answer (score 13):

I realized the xcproject file was opened instead of the updated workspace. This fixed my error. Hope this information will help others too.

Comment: As a newbie to cocoapods I didn't even realize I was supposed to open the xcworkspace instead of the xcproject.  That seems obvious now, but it's really not very obvious from the cocoapods guides I've read.

Comment: this was it! prayers.

Answer (score 10):

If none of the other answers help you, try this:

- Deintegrate cocoa pods using `pod deintegrate`. Check this link https://github.com/kylef/cocoapods-deintegrate.
- Search on the build settings for target and project file for "pod". Anything that looks like it belonged to cocoa pods, remove.
- Finally, run `pod install` once again.

Comment: pod deintegrate is real timesaver for me!

Comment: Nice in theory, but pod install for some reason isn't putting everything back in to build correctly after the deintegrate.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme... > Build > + > Add the Pods-Projectname.a and drag it to the top > Clean & Build your project.

Answer (score 6):

I had a very different experience. I tried removed the library from build settings to no avail. And honestly, I couldn't see the logic behind it.

What I did was try a new `pod install`. And so it gave me this error

> [!] The ProjectName [Debug] target overrides the LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS build setting defined in Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-/Pods-.debug.xcconfig. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
>       - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
>       - Remove the build settings from the target.
>
> [!] The ProjectName [Release] target overrides the LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS build setting defined in Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-/Pods-.debug.xcconfig. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
>       - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
>       - Remove the build settings from the target.

So I did what it told me to, I added the `$(inherited)` flag to build settings. And all worked well

Comment: Solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I found that a mis-match of deployment target of the Project (iOS 11.4) versus the Target (iOS 10.3). Updating the target to iOS 11.4 fixed the issue.

Project > Info > Deployment Target > iOS Deployment Target
Project > Target > General > Deployment Target > Target

Podfile:
`platform :ios, '11.4'`

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem when I accidentally opened project instead of workspace so Cocoapods where missing....

Answer (score 3):

Check your Project -> Targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Point to your Pods project, set the BaseSDK to iOS SDK since 'pod install' process clear it.
Also set Build Valid Architecture Only to NO
That should work.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar error which affected one of my computers but not the other when compiling the same project.

I reinstalled cocoapods, all gems, rebuilt the project and none of it worked.  I finally got it to compile but required me to completely remove Xcode and related data (iPhone simulator, DerivedData) then reinstall Xcode.

Comment: Oh, seems like it was hard.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this error after adding a new build configuration.

`pod install` helped, because it adds separate settings for each build configuration.

Answer (score 0):

i also had the same sort of issue. So Check your pod file's **platform :ios** . and check **Deployment info** target versions. and please make sure version of both files are same. if both are not same the issue will be executed. i also had the issue after library updating my react native project

(Target info = select your project, then select target, In general section Deployment info is available.)

[image]

[image]