# Cocoapods ld: library not found for -lPods-ObjectiveSugar

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I’m getting this error when I try and build on Xcode (6.4). I have two targets, but for now I just want at least one of them to work.

`ld: library not found for -lPods-ObjectiveSugar`

Here’s my podfile (it is set up for two targets, but I had only one before with same error):

```
target ‘AppName_iOS' do

pod 'ObjectiveSugar', '~> 1.1'
pod 'SWRevealViewController', '~> 2.3'
pod 'Masonry', '~> 0.6'

pod 'AUISelectiveBordersView', '~> 0.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6'
#pod 'DSNestedAccordion', '~> 0.1'

pod 'SparkInspector'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 2.0'

end

target 'AppName_iOS_CI' do

pod 'ObjectiveSugar', '~> 1.1'
pod 'SWRevealViewController', '~> 2.3'
pod 'Masonry', '~> 0.6'

pod 'AUISelectiveBordersView', '~> 0.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6'
#pod 'DSNestedAccordion', '~> 0.1'

pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 2.0'

end
```

I moved ObjectiveSugar down the list and still got issues with it, so I went ahead and removed the library and linked it myself, outside of cocoa pods. The issue still remains.

Tried everything on this post:
[Cocoapods ld: library not found for -lPods-Projectname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078597/cocoapods-ld-library-not-found-for-lpods-projectname)

- Removing and adding the library again (pod install) Deleting the
  -lPods-Projectname.a in Link Binary ( deleting binary from link binary with libraries on App target, build phases.)
- Tried Build Active Architectures YES and NO.
- Tried pod deintegrate and then pod install.

I haven’t uninstalled Xcode, and reinstalled cocoa pods, etc… That seems overkill.

Also tried everything in this troubleshooting guide http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html (4. If Xcode complains when linking)

Let me know if you need more info. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the issue.

On Xcode, build settings for the target, I searched for "Other Linker Flags". There I had this:

`-l"Pods-ObjectiveSugar`

This was some kind of workaround I did several months back to fix some issue. Can't remember what, at this point. Removing it solved the issue.

What I did, just to be safe, was:

- I deintegrated cocoa pods, using `pod deintegrate`. Check this link https://github.com/kylef/cocoapods-deintegrate.
- I searched on the target settings and project file for `pod`. Anything that looked like it belonged to cocoa pods, I removed.
- Then I ran `pod install` once again.

Hope this helps other lost souls.