# Cocoapods : ld: library not found for -lBolts

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am using cocoapods in one of my projects and after I cleaned the derived data for my project I have started seeing this error

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vishal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SensorLab-ctzyiyrpdclyjybpujriezgkckkn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Bolts'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vishal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SensorLab-ctzyiyrpdclyjybpujriezgkckkn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/DownPicker'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vishal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SensorLab-ctzyiyrpdclyjybpujriezgkckkn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MBProgressHUD'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vishal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SensorLab-ctzyiyrpdclyjybpujriezgkckkn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Parse'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vishal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SensorLab-ctzyiyrpdclyjybpujriezgkckkn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SCLAlertView-Objective-C'
ld: library not found for -lBolts
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I open up the *Debug-iphoneos* from *Window > Projects* I do not see any folders in there now. Since this problem started cropping up after cleaning derived data I do not really know what did I do which stopped generating those folders.

This is how it looks :
[image]

This is kind of how it should look, I imagine (From a different project)
[image]

I have tried what was suggested here

[Cocoapods ld: library not found for -lPods-Projectname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078597/cocoapods-ld-library-not-found-for-lpods-projectname)

[Cocoapods ld: library not found for -lPods-ObjectiveSugar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768516/cocoapods-ld-library-not-found-for-lpods-objectivesugar)

And a couple more things which I have tried but to no avail, I have faced my fair share of cocoapod niggles. This seems beyond me.

EDIT: I have been doing some more tests with this, I realized that my pods are not even building ! When I clear derived data for any other project, it goes ahead and builds the Pods next time I try to build the project, but not in this project. What setting can wrong ?

This is how the project looks right now : 
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is your cocoapod version?

Comment: @MayankPatel I was using 1.0.1, then out  of desperation I upgraded to 1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Clean up cocoa pods and install them again.[image]

You can also use tool - https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate

Comment: I have already done that. Deintegrated it and integrated it all over again. The three steps you have highlighted are present in the build phases as well.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the option of *Find Implicit Dependencies* got turned off in the build scheme. SMH.
Hope this can help someone in the future.

[image]