# 1Password Pods iOS library not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I resume an project from someone else in my company who make a iOS apps using 1password pods.

i have a build error , i search on the web but i dont found a solution.

maybe can you help me.

here the error :

ld: library not found for -l1PasswordExtension
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Did you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863836/library-not-found-for-lpods?rq=1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this problem a few times when using cocoapods. Some of the solutions on this SO post have helped me before [Cocoapods ld: library not found for -lPods-Projectname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078597/cocoapods-ld-library-not-found-for-lpods-projectname)

Also, the official cocoapods site has some help for this issue on their troubleshooting page https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html:

> If Xcode complains when linking, e.g. Library not found for -lPods, it doesn't detect the implicit dependencies:
>
> > Go to Product > Edit Scheme
> >
> > Click on Build
> >     Add the Pods static library, and make sure it's at the top of the list
> >
> > Clean and build again
> >
> > If that doesn't work, verify that the source for the spec you are trying to include has been pulled from GitHub. Do this by looking in /Pods/. If it is empty (it should not be), verify that the ~/.cocoapods/master//.podspec has the correct git hub url in it.
> >
> > If still doesn't work, check your Xcode build locations settings. Go to Preferences -> Locations -> Derived Data -> Advanced and set build location to "Relative to Workspace".

If all else fails, you can always try deleting the Xcode workspace and the Pods directory, then re-running 'pod install' to see if that clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rob T, i edit the scheme and now it's work.

just before to run i made a pod install.