# Xcode: library not found for -lPods

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

Having a react-native project, which won't build on target "Staging" since I've setup cocoapods and using `xcworkspace` file since then (needed for firebase integration of `react-native-firebase`). When trying to build for taget "staging", I'll get this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-[app]
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

It works on debug, and (well at least it doesn't throw an error) when I archive the project.

I've having a "staging" target because of code-push. Using react-native at version `0.48.4` and Xcode 9 (created it following [this guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/multi-deployment-testing-ios.md), but before using cocoapods)

My podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'xx' do
  #use_frameworks!

  # Pods 
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'

end
```

Tried with and without `use_frameworks!`, cleaning project, deleted DerivedData, deintegrating and reintegrating pods.

What could cause this? (Please tell me if you need more information)

Comment: Go to Build Phases and check if the framework is added in the “Link Binary with Libraries” tab

Comment: It is (`libPods-[projectName].a` with status `required`)

Comment: Set $(inherited) in the Library Search Paths. If that does not work you can try to set "Build Active architecture Only" to YES

Comment: I have already `$(inherited)` on all targets (in the project column). Can you tell me how I should set "Build Active Architecture Only" properly? I'm having columns: "Resolved" (not editable, says "YES" on debug, empty on Release/Staging), [Target], Config.file (not editable), [Project]. Tried it with same values as debug has (setting [Target] to YES), cleaned and rebuild, but still fails.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What worked for me:

1. Deintegrated all pods using `pod deintegrate` (using [enter link description here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate))
2. `pod install`
3. Removed [Project name] > Frameworks > Pods_[Project name].framework (which was red, but there are actually more files being red)
4. Build succeeded

Was doing this with the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24100063/1340707). Thanks also to Maurice for trying to help me.

Comment: After each pod install i need to do Removed [Project name] > Frameworks > Pods_[Project name].framework is it possible to do it automatically because i have issue in CI

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue. In my case it was a react-native app added Firebase Analytics. As of July 2018, all apps must be built with iOS 11 per Apple:  developer.apple.com/ios/submit/

Once I went to my General tab and scrolled down to Deployment Info / Deployment Target and changed it from 10.x which is what I was targeting, to 11.x - the app built/archived and I was able to submit.

Comment: This worked for me. Strange because my project was building fine today. (I hadn't built it in a few months ) but started failing when I tried adding another pod and failed even when I reset, clean project and temp files but setting from 9.3 to 11 worked.

Comment: btw: After successful build I changed it back to 9.3 just to test. It works in dev. I'll see about submitting to the store.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set your [PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M48uB.png) of "staging" as "release" ${PODS_BUILD_DIR}/Release$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME).
2. Check the Frameworks folder and remove red files.

Answer (score 0):

check whether the SEARCH_PATHS is correct at `Pods-XXXX.debug.xcconfig` or `Pods-XXXX.release.xcconfig`

[image]

`LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "$(PODS_ROOT)/path/to/your folder"`