# React-native, duplicated scheme fails to link pods

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

we have a react-native project, due to our requirements we ended duplicating the "release" scheme, so we have a "staging" scheme, we are changing the identifier, so we can have multiple apps depending on the scheme we use to compile the app. but nothing else.

The problem came when we had to integrate cocoapods for one our dependencies, we did a normal install and everything was working, now we need to remove one of this dependencies, the problem is now when we try to build the app with the staging scheme, we get the following error:

`ld: library not found for -lPods-(our-app-name)`

Nothing seems to be working, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078597/cocoapods-ld-library-not-found-for-lpods-projectname

Answer (score 0):

It seems at some point cocoapods changed the linking model, so it might no longer be necessary to link the libPods.a library, I simply removed it and project compiles again, and everything (seems) to be working again.